# ReactJS form rendering each text input change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-redux, text-rendering

I have the problem that I have a function inside render() that will output each input text, that is, it prints letter by letter instead of word by word. I have tried to put the function outside render() but then it does not work. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

//Declaring the ethereum client (initializing) with the url in which the testrpc is running
var ETHEREUM_CLIENT = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

//These could be dynamically added through input fields, but hard coding for now
var peopleContractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeople","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"email","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_email","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

var peopleContractAddress = '0xa0b4dccf81cb4bc6cdb890637dc02b62a7a35b66'

var peopleContract = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract(peopleContractABI).at(peopleContractAddress)

//Need to create a variable named accounts in order to know which account
//to make the transactions from
var accounts = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.accounts

//Creating the dynamic input fields for the user to input his/her data
export class Form extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
  }

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, key) {
    this.setState({[key]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A user was submitted: ' + this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName + this.state.email);
    event.preventdefault();
  }


/*Creating so that person can be added
  componentWillMount(){
     this.setState({
       firstName: this.state.firstName,
       lastName: this.state.lastName,
       email: this.state.email
     })
 }
 */

  render() {
    peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <h4>Name</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="e.g. Bob"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'firstName')}  />
        <div>
        <h4>Last Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="e.g. Stark"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'lastName')}/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h4>Email</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="e.g. bobstark@gmail.com"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'email')}/>
        </div>
        <input
          type = "submit"
          name = "Submit"
          />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to only call `peopleContract.addPerson` when a word is complete? Seems a bit odd. Person sounds like an entity why would you keep calling add entity on every word change?

Comment: This would be in order to add the input of the user as firstName, lastName and email into the parameters that are required by the function

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when user start typing every new key in input changed state and that your component call render method.

Good idea is move

`peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})`

outside render method.

Than in this.handleChange method you can decide base on event.target.value and state to call peopleContract.addPerson or not. and set new state. I guess you are trying do some like autocomplete ?

But if you need filled fields to call peopleContract.addPerson you can do that in handleSubmit.

Comment: How would you add a condition to know when the field is completed in handleSubmit?

Comment: When user did submit. In submit method you have access to state and all inputs values you have in state. So than you can check if fields are not empty. Than you can can display error  or call peopleContract.addPerson.

if you wanna do something like autocomplet you can do that in handleChange.

I am not sure what you need to do.

Comment: I need to get the complete firstName, lastName and email that the user inputs into the text fields in the form, and pass these values to `peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})`

Comment: I will answer in separate answer I can add code there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call this function inside some method. You should do it inside a lifecycle method.

```
import React from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';
```

//Declaring the ethereum client (initializing) with the url in which the testrpc is running

```
var ETHEREUM_CLIENT = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))
```

//These could be dynamically added through input fields, but hard coding for now

```
var peopleContractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeople","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"email","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_email","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

var peopleContractAddress = '0xa0b4dccf81cb4bc6cdb890637dc02b62a7a35b66'

var peopleContract = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract(peopleContractABI).at(peopleContractAddress)

//Need to create a variable named accounts in order to know which account
//to make the transactions from
var accounts = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.accounts

//Creating the dynamic input fields for the user to input his/her data
export class Form extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
  }

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, key) {
    this.setState({[key]: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A user was submitted: ' + this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName + this.state.email);
    event.preventdefault();
  }


/*Creating so that person can be added
  componentWillMount(){
     this.setState({
       firstName: this.state.firstName,
       lastName: this.state.lastName,
       email: this.state.email
     })
 }
 */


  componentDidMount(){
        peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName,     this.state.email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
 }


  render() {
   // peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <h4>Name</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="e.g. Bob"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'firstName')}  />
        <div>
        <h4>Last Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="e.g. Stark"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'lastName')}/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h4>Email</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="e.g. bobstark@gmail.com"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'email')}/>
        </div>
        <input
          type = "submit"
          name = "Submit"
          />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import Web3 from 'web3';

//Declaring the ethereum client (initializing) with the url in which the testrpc is running
var ETHEREUM_CLIENT = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"))

//These could be dynamically added through input fields, but hard coding for now
var peopleContractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getPeople","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"},{"name":"","type":"bytes32[]"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"people","outputs":[{"name":"firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"email","type":"bytes32"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_firstName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_lastName","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"_email","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"addPerson","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"}]

var peopleContractAddress = '0xa0b4dccf81cb4bc6cdb890637dc02b62a7a35b66'

var peopleContract = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.contract(peopleContractABI).at(peopleContractAddress)

//Need to create a variable named accounts in order to know which account
//to make the transactions from
var accounts = ETHEREUM_CLIENT.eth.accounts

//Creating the dynamic input fields for the user to input his/her data
export class Form extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
  }

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event, key) {
    this.setState({[key]: event.target.value});
  }

   handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A user was submitted: ' + this.state.firstName + this.state.lastName + this.state.email);
    event.preventdefault();

    if((this.state.firstName!=="") && (this.state.lastName!=="")&& (this.state.email!==""){
        peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})

        // after you subimt vlaues clear state 
        this.setState({
            firstName: this.state.firstName,
            lastName: this.state.lastName,
            email: this.state.email
        })
    }else{
        // render error 
        alert('Some fileds are mandatory');
    }
}


/*Creating so that person can be added
  componentWillMount(){
     this.setState({
       firstName: this.state.firstName,
       lastName: this.state.lastName,
       email: this.state.email
     })
 }
 */

  render() {
    // Do not call this method here peopleContract.addPerson(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, this.state.email, {from: accounts[1], gas: 3000000})
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <h4>Name</h4>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="e.g. Bob"
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'firstName')}  />
        <div>
        <h4>Last Name</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="e.g. Stark"
            value={this.state.lastName}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'lastName')}/>
        </div>
        <div>
        <h4>Email</h4>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="e.g. bobstark@gmail.com"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, 'email')}/>
        </div>
        <input
          type = "submit"
          name = "Submit"
          />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try 

this.setState({ ...state, state[key]: event.target.value});

Comment: You mean writing that in the `handleChange(event, key)`? Because writing it that way gives an error